# Running C Program script in Linux gives error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: linux

I keep getting this error on Linux while running a C program.
line3: syntax error near unexpected token `(' line3:` int main()'
Here is the simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Even after including #!/bin/bash at top, the error stays

Comment: @Shawn This shows up when I run the script ./script.c on Terminal

Comment: Uh... it's a C program, not a shell script. You have to compile it with a C compiler.

Comment: @Shawn I compiled it with gcc shell.c -o shell and it still shows that error.

Comment: @DanilaKiver I do I execute that 'c' script?

Comment: After `gcc shell.c -o shell`, you'll get that error if you run `./shell.c`. Run `./shell` instead. A C source file cannot [*] be executed directly. It can be compiled to generate an executable file, and that file can be executed. `shell` is the executable file. [*] *There are systems that let you run C programs, like tcc, but they're not relevant here.*.

Comment: @VipulPriyadarshi You need to run the compiled output. You cannot run the C code itself. The compiled output does not have a line 3 and so cannot produce such an error as you report.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yea that worked. I always ran ./shell.c instead ./shell was the right one. Thank you

Comment: Incidentally, C programs are not generally called "scripts". A script is a program that can be interpreted directly by some interpreter (bash, python, etc.). A C program is compiled, not interpreted.

Comment: C programming is done in three stages: 1) First you edit the source file. 2) Build the source into an executable program. 3) Run the executable program created by step 2. You *don't* run the source file (C is not an interpreted "script" language). This should have been taught by just about any decent book, tutorial or class. Either you skipped part of the introduktion, or your books/tutorials/clases are really bad.

Comment: In Linux I always ran the the source file for bash script so I was doing the same with c script. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compile c code.  First remove the #!/bin/bash from the top. Then try this:

```
gcc -o script script.c
```

this will build your program and output it to a binary file called script.
you can then run it like this:

```
./script
```